# Find nearest waypoint

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, game-development

Task: is to make a list from the closest waypoint on scene to the farthest
but script every time adding a same waypoint to newRoute.

Enemy with waypoints on scene:

[image: scene]

I'm trying to avoid it[!newRoute.Contains(waypoints[c]], but it doesn't work

```
List<Transform> GenerateNewRouteT()
{
    List<Transform> newRoute = new List<Transform>();
    Transform currentNearestWaypoint = waypoints[waypoints.Count - 1];

    for (byte v = 0; v < waypoints.Count; v++)
    {
        for (byte c = 0; c < waypoints.Count; c++)
        {
            if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, waypoints[c].position) < Vector3.Distance(transform.position, currentNearestWaypoint.position) && !newRoute.Contains(waypoints[c]))
            {
                currentNearestWaypoint = waypoints[c];
            }
        }
        newRoute.Add(currentNearestWaypoint);
        Debug.Log($"Added waypoint with coordinates: {currentNearestWaypoint.position.ToString()}");
    }


    return newRoute;
}
```

I can't use [SerializeField] cause mob creating from prefab

Comment: Please, add the code as text in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need to modify your logic to:

1. Find the closest waypoint to the player.
2. Find the closest waypoint to the previous waypoint (repeat).

---

```
List<Transform> waypoints = new List<Transform>();
List<Transform> route = new List<Transform>();
Transform currentWaypoint = null;

// Start from the player.
currentWaypoint = FindClosestWaypoint(transform);

// Fill the route with waypoints.
for (int i = 0; i < waypoints.Count; i++)
{
    currentWaypoint = FindClosestWaypoint(currentWaypoint);
    if(currentWaypoint != null) route.Add(currentWaypoint);
}

Transform FindClosestWaypoint(Transform from)
{
    // Default to the first element.
    Transform closestWaypoint = waypoints[0];
    var smallestDistance = Vector3.Distance(from.position, closestWaypoint.position);
    
    foreach (var waypoint in waypoints)
    {
        // Skip when element is already in the route.
        if (route.Contains(waypoint)) continue;

        // Update closest waypoint/distance.
        var distance = Vector3.Distance(from.position, waypoint.position);
        if (distance < smallestDistance)
        {
            closestWaypoint = waypoint;
            smallestDistance = distance;
        }
    }

    return closestWaypoint;
}
```

Comment: same error, added below comment with code and screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Scene: https://ibb.co/q5H5spX

Maybe the mistake is in another method?

```
public class MobMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] public float enemySpeed;
    [HideInInspector] public byte _currentWaypointIndex = 0;

    [SerializeField] public GameObject fisrtSpawnpoint;

    private List<Transform> waypoints = new List<Transform>();
    private bool generateNewRoute = false;

    void Start()
    {
        InitializeWaypoints();
        CheckRoute();
        if (generateNewRoute)
        {
            waypoints = GenerateNewRoute();
            Debug.LogWarning("Generated new route");
            for (byte c = 0; c < waypoints.Count; c++)
            {
                Debug.Log(waypoints[c].position.ToString());
            }
            // for (byte c = 0; c < waypoints.Count; c++)
            // {
            //     Debug.Log($"{c}: X:{waypoints[c].position.x.ToString()} Z:{waypoints[c].position.z.ToString()}");
            // }a
        }
    }

    void InitializeWaypoints()
    {
        foreach (GameObject respawn in GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Waypoint"))
        {
            waypoints.Add(respawn.transform);
            //Debug.LogWarning("Found and added this point to waypoints list");
        }

        if (waypoints != null && waypoints.Count != 0)
        {
            //Debug.Log("Added waypoints in list for new mob");
            //Debug.LogWarning($"{waypoints.Count.ToString()}");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Check code waypoints list is empty right now...");
        }
    }
    void CheckRoute()
    {
        GameObject spawnpoint = GameObject.Find("Spawnpoint1");

        if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, spawnpoint.transform.position) < 3)
        {
            //Debug.Log("Following route from first spawnpoint");
            RouteFrom1Spawnpoint firstRoute = new RouteFrom1Spawnpoint();
            firstRoute.FollowRoute(ref waypoints, ref generateNewRoute);
        }
        else
        {
            //Debug.Log("Following route from 2 spawnpoint");
            RouteFrom2Spawnpoint secondRoute = new RouteFrom2Spawnpoint();
            secondRoute.FollowRoute(ref waypoints, ref generateNewRoute);
        }
    }
    List<Transform> GenerateNewRoute()
    {
        List<Transform> route = new List<Transform>();
        Transform currentWaypoint = null;

        // Start from the player.
        currentWaypoint = FindClosestWaypoint(transform);

        // Fill the route with waypoints.
        for (byte i = 0; i < waypoints.Count; i++)
        {
            currentWaypoint = FindClosestWaypoint(currentWaypoint);
            if (currentWaypoint != null) route.Add(currentWaypoint);
        }

        Transform FindClosestWaypoint(Transform from)
        {
            // Default to the first element.
            Transform closestWaypoint = waypoints[0];
            var smallestDistance = Vector3.Distance(from.position, closestWaypoint.position);

            foreach (var waypoint in waypoints)
            {
                // Skip when element is already in the route.
                if (route.Contains(waypoint)) continue;

                // Update closest waypoint/distance.
                var distance = Vector3.Distance(from.position, waypoint.position);
                if (distance < smallestDistance)
                {
                    closestWaypoint = waypoint;
                    smallestDistance = distance;
                }
            }
            return closestWaypoint;
        }
        return route;
    }
    List<Transform> GenerateNewRouteT()
    {
        List<Transform> newRoute = new List<Transform>();
        Transform currentNearestWaypoint = waypoints[waypoints.Count - 1];

        for (byte v = 0; v < waypoints.Count; v++)
        {
            for (byte c = 0; c < waypoints.Count; c++)
            {
                if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, waypoints[c].position) < Vector3.Distance(transform.position, currentNearestWaypoint.position) && !newRoute.Contains(waypoints[c]))
                {
                    currentNearestWaypoint = waypoints[c];
                }
            }
            newRoute.Add(currentNearestWaypoint);
            Debug.Log($"Added waypoint with coordinates: {currentNearestWaypoint.position.ToString()}");
        }
        return newRoute;
    }
    void Update()
    {
        Movement();
    }
    private void Movement()
    {
        //check spwawnpoint 
        if (_currentWaypointIndex < waypoints.Count)
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, waypoints[_currentWaypointIndex].position, Time.deltaTime * enemySpeed);
            transform.LookAt(waypoints[_currentWaypointIndex].position);
            if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, waypoints[_currentWaypointIndex].position) < 0.5f)
            {
                _currentWaypointIndex++;
            }
        }
    }
    abstract class RouteFollower
    {
        public abstract void FollowRoute(ref List<Transform> listOfWaypoints, ref bool generateNewRoute);
    }

    class RouteFrom1Spawnpoint : RouteFollower
    {
        public override void FollowRoute(ref List<Transform> listOfWaypoints, ref bool generateNewRoute)
        {
            List<Transform> newRoute = new List<Transform>();
            newRoute.Add(listOfWaypoints[8]);
            listOfWaypoints = newRoute;
            generateNewRoute = false;
        }
    }
    class RouteFrom2Spawnpoint : RouteFollower
    {
        public override void FollowRoute(ref List<Transform> listOfWaypoints, ref bool generateNewRoute)
        {
            generateNewRoute = true;
        }
    }
}
```